# Как передать id нажатого объекта Listview в курсор на 2й активити?

Tags: база-данных, android-studio, sqlite, listview, запрос

Есть база данных с повторяющимися значениями и надо ,что бы по нажатию на элемент первого столбца показывался второй столбец , где в строчке первого столбца - нажатый пункт.

Т.е из таблицы

```
 Компания |  Модель 
--------------------
    1     |     a
    1     |     b
    2     |     c
    2     |     d
```

Т.е что бы по нажатию на 1 мне вывело только a и b. Старт новой активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Model.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Создание и работа с курсором в первой активити:

```
db = databaseHelper.open();

//получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE + " group by " + COLUMN_COMP  , null );

// определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
String[] headers = new String[]{COLUMN_COMP};

// создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
CAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    c, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

if (!EditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
     CAdapter.getFilter().filter(EditText.getText().toString());
}
```

Во второй активити так же, но курсор вот такой:

```
c = db.rawQuery("select " +  " _id, Model " + " from " + TABLE + " where Comp='Вот сюда надо подставить, как я понимаю"
```

Работа с бд вынесена в отдельный класс. Как именно надо передать нажатый элемент? Желательно с объяснениями.

Comment: Зачем передавать курсор в адаптер?
Ты должен подготовить заранее список с моделями и скормить адаптеру. Нарушается Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: Но если у меня таких колонок 5, и надо таким образом дойти до 5й , то постоянно создавать измененные таблицы?

Comment: С трудом понимаю вопрос. Однозначно лишь могу сказать, что у вас неправильная архитектура. Вы написали "Как передать id нажатого объекта Listview в курсор на 2й активити?" и сами же привели код как передали id через intent. Сложность в том, как его вставить в строку? Тогда так: c = db.rawQuery("select " +  " _id, Model " + " from " + TABLE + " where Comp='" + id + "'"

Comment: Да, извините, это был тестовый вариант, проверил как оно именно работает. 
Задача такая: Есть таблица из 5ти столбцов, где данные в каждом столбце могут повторяться. Сначала пользователь выбирает Компанию, потом модели этой компании, потом еще несколько уточняющих активити - узел запчастей в этой модели и саму запчасть., дальше о ней выводится какая- либо информация

Comment: Если данные в таблице повторяются, это уже не правильно. Делайте отдельную таблицу для каждой сущности и связывайте их между собой ключами

Comment: А можно подробнее и с небольшими примерами , как это делать и что должно получиться в итоге?

Comment: Это преподается на первом курсе любого вуза. Это базовые знания, без которых нельзя проектировать базу данных. http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8